# Compile opencv as part of project with cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

How can I compile Cmake source code as part of my project. Say I cloned opencv from github in my `app/external` directory and there is one executable as `/app/main.cpp`. CMake's `find_package()` and `find_library()` commands does not works because I only have the source code and want to start compiling process of opencv with my app.

I am aware of there are other easy methods about linking opencv to executable but I want do at this way for this project. All suggestions are welcomed.

project structure be like

```
/app
  /external
    /opencv
  main.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Which repo did you clone? Does it contain `CMakeLists.txt` configuration?

Comment: I cloned this repo : git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git, it contains CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Did you try just adding it with `add_subdirectory(external/opencv)`? If so, what issues did you come across?

Comment: I tried but I guess I couldn't link my executable with opencv libraries. Error was `there is no such a file <opencv2/core.hpp>`

Comment: Check an [example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/cpp/example_cmake/CMakeLists.txt) on how to use cmake of opencv

Comment: I tried this approach already. But as I know this approach searchs for installed any OpenCV library on the system. I want to compile opencv as part of my project, not to search and link dynamically installed opencv binaries.